# Can not decode data from serial port arduino send to mqtt server mosquitto

Tags: node.js, mqtt, mosquitto, arduino-esp8266, atmega16

I'm used ESP8266 receive data from atmega328pb via Serial and send these data to my MQTT broker (mosquitto). From server side I use NodeJS receive buffer but can not convert these data to string.

```
Sample buffer:
<Buffer 2b a1 71 2f c5 2b c2 d0 dc ec 3a 04 8c 62 4a 05 0d 0a>

Convert to Json:
{"type":"Buffer","data":[43,161,113,47,197,43,194,208,220,236,58,4,140,98,74,5,13,10]}

Convert to String uft8:
+�q/�+����:�bJ

My default text: 0100001100
```

How to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66825571/edit) the question to show the actual code you are using.

Comment: Very sorry, These data are AES. Can i close this question?

Comment: There is a link to delete the question under the list of tags

Comment: Convert to what string?  Its binary data -- is it supposed to be a human readable string?!?